# How can I return the most recent joined member from my arraylist?

Tags: java, loops, iterator

I am trying to find the most recent member joined in my arraylist of people for a gym club. My thought process is finding the highest year and then the highest month but I am having trouble executing it.

Here are the members of the club:

```
club.join(new Membership("Ellen", 2, 2016, 115.00));
        club.join(new Membership("Eric", 1, 2017, 75.00));
        club.join(new Membership("Ben", 3, 2015, 35.50));
        club.join(new Membership("Matt", 12, 2014, 42.00));
        club.join(new Membership("Luke", 5, 2010, 145.00));
        club.join(new Membership("Jon", 6, 2017, 65.00));
        club.join(new Membership("Ryan", 7, 2016, 0.00));
        club.join(new Membership("Alan", 8, 2015, 195.00));
        club.join(new Membership("Jaden", 9, 2015, 15.00));
        club.join(new Membership("Dan P", 10, 2011, 25.00));
        club.join(new Membership("Jack", 2, 2013, 80.75));
        club.join(new Membership("Mrs. R", 1, 2014, 125.00));
        club.join(new Membership("Dan S", 1, 2015, 45.00));
        club.join(new Membership("Caleb", 10, 2016, 0.00));
        club.join(new Membership("Jacob", 5, 2017, 10.00));
        club.join(new Membership("Anny", 7, 2016, 110.00));
        club.join(new Membership("Wendy", 7, 2015, 85.00));
        club.join(new Membership("Natalie", 8, 2014, 0.00));
        club.join(new Membership("Paul", 9, 2016, 20.00));
        club.join(new Membership("Zuck", 10, 2017, 55.00));
```

And here is my code for the find most recent method:

```
int tempMonth = 13;
        int tempYear = 3000;
        ArrayList<Membership> ppl = new ArrayList<Membership>();
        Iterator<Membership> itr = members.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext())
        {
            Membership item = itr.next();
            if(members.size() == 0)
            {
                return null;
            }
            else
            {
                if(tempYear > item.getYear())
                {
                    if(tempMonth > item.getMonth())
                    {
                        ppl.add(item);
                        itr.remove();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return ppl;
```

Comment: Wouldn't tempYear>item.getYear be true for every member? Why set it to 3000

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Collections.max` and custom `Comparator` to sort the list of `Membership`

```
Collections.max(members, Comparator.comparing(Membership::getYear)
                                   .thenComparing(Membership::getMonth));
```

You can also do the same using `stream`

```
members.stream().max(//comparator)
```